# Is there a centralized location for the sources or homepages of RPM packages in CentOS?

Tags: centos, rpm, licenses

I'm trying to find a source or homepage for the rpm packages in CentOS that have copyleft licensing, like GPL, and there doesn't seem to be a centralized way to find them other than exhaustive searching and looking in `/usr/share/doc/`. Is there a centralized location for this information, or is it all piecemeal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `dnf`:

```
dnf repoquery --queryformat '%{name} %{license}\n'
```

e,g:

```
dnf repoquery --queryformat '%{name} %{license}\n' |grep BSD
```

Answer (score 2):

```
yum info package_name

rpm -qi package_name
```

Those will show info for the package including the License and the URL.